# React invalid hook call error with functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

here is my code :

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
    import {  getDiagramId } from '@app/wireframes/model';
    
    const HOC = () => {
        
        const storeContext = React.useContext(ReactReduxContext);
        const diagram = () => {
            const selectedDiagramId = getDiagramId(storeContext.store.getState());
    
            console.log(selectedDiagramId);
        };
    
        return (diagram);
    };
    export default HOC;
```

ERROR:
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
I get the same error no matter what I did, what could be the reason and solution?

Comment: Not enough info, and your HOC is not even a proper HOC because it takes zero arguments.

Comment: @JosephWang want  to use hook functions in class but unfortunately when i call a function like useContext, useStore i get this error.

Also why do I need to provide parameters for the HOC?